# Why does my first deployment work but all subsequent deployments fail to get an instance?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an app that has several services - this happens for all of them but below is data for the **data-dev** service:

If i deploy any of the services to a blank project - i.e. one where there are no services with that name yet, they all deploy fine with this command:

`gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote`

If i then make changes to the app, and run the same command again - the console hangs on `Updating service [data-dev] (this may take several minutes)` for over two hours - never crashes - no errors.

If I go into the service and look at versions, there are the 'new' versions but they never seem to be given an instance to run on - here are a few i deployed with the following command to make finding them easier in logs etc:

[image: versions]

`gcloud -q app deploy app.yaml --promote --version=devX`

If i look at the logs for any of these versions - i get the following as the only entry:

[image: picture of logs]

What makes this even more annoying is - i can't delete the service when i have all these things 'pending' because:

[image: error when trying to delete services]

I have to quite literally go into the settings for the whole app, disable it, wait 15 mins for all of the services to turn off, then re-enable it to delete the a single service - once i delete the service i am again able to deploy the thing (once) without any problems - all subsequent deployments fail as described.

**Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening or, how to debug this?**

Here is the **app.yaml**:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: data-dev
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are not getting this to work is because there are no available instances - you are specifying 1 for the service so when you try to deploy another, there are no more instances to deploy to - you can achieve the behaviour you want (i.e. 1 instance) with the following app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
service: data-prod
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 20
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.7
```

you can tweak max_num_instances as you need, but make sure you have enough for deployments!

Answer (score 1):

You can check what is going on with the instance where your GAE flex app is running by going to the logs and setting an advanced filter with `resource.type="gce_instance" AND "aef-"` (the **a**pp **e**ngine **f**lex instances are labeled with `aef-<service_id>-<version_id>-<random_digits>`).

There you'll see more details of what your instances are doing, and you'll be able to better debug what is going on.

Generally, when a deployment is not successful (but the deployment is allowed) is because the instances are considered unhealthy by not properly responding to the healthchecks, but you should check the logs to know more details.